# How to change all Kendoui grid cell into edit mode

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm customizing the Kendoui grid template and found that i need only all the cell in edit mode all time. How do i change all the cell into edit mode? programmatically or in setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supported editing modes allow only one cell or row to be editable at a time. You can however use the column template to do that. And you need to use MVVM so the values are updated. Here is some sample code:

#### View

```
<!-- grid declaration -->
<div id="grid" 
     data-row-template="row-template"
     data-role="grid"     
     data-sortable="true"
     data-bind="source: dataSource">    
</div>
<!-- grid row template -->      
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<tr data-uid="#=uid#">
  <td>
      <input data-bind="value: name" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input data-role="numerictextbox" data-bind="value: age" />
  </td>
</tr>
</script>
```

#### View-model

```
<script>
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 31 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ]
});

kendo.bind(document.body, viewModel);
</script>
```